# R (beginner) : Using R functions in excel (RExcel)

Tags: r, excel

I have coded a project in R and I would like to export my functions to R.

Is there an add-in or any other way enabling such functionality ?

**Edit**

After Dabbiemiller's answer I followed the installation procedure and I successfully installed rcom and RExcel. However I am not able to use it. I have the following error message when trying to start RExcel in Excel 2010:

> There seems to be no R process connected to Excel

Could someone help me with this latest problem please?

Many thanks

Comment: Check this post http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/

Comment: @beginneR: Thanks ! Would you have an idea about how to help me with my new problem? (see my edit)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with RExcel or connecting excel and R in general.

Comment: did you install DCOM?

Answer (score 1):

From my first google search, here's a try : http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html#RExcel.
Good Luck.

Comment: Many thanks! I've installed it properly but I can't use it. I have this error message when trying to start RExcel in Excel 2010: "There seems to be no R process connected to Excel". Could you help me with it please.